# class properties verification for null and length of string

Tags: asp.net, function, c#-4.0, properties

I've to pass the class properties to the function but need to check for NULL and specific length. i tried to calling the function CheckProperty from inside UserInfo class but gives error ::

1. "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property UserInfo.CheckProperty(string, int) "
2. "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property UserInfo.UserAddr.get"

public class clsUserBookKeeping
    {

```
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }   
        public string UserName { get; set; } // length should not exceed 20 characters, if NULL pass "TBD"
        public string UserAddr { get; set; } // length should not exceed 120 characters, if NULL pass "TBD"
        public string UserContact { get; set; } // length should not exceed 20 characters, if NULL pass "TBD"
    }

    var output = getRecord (UserInfo.UserId, UserInfo.UserName, UserInfo.UserAddr, UserInfo.UserContact);

    private string CheckProperty(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return "TBD";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length > maxLength)
        {
            return value.Substring(0, maxLength);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

**note : public class clsUserBookKeeping is the class, it is going out of code block.**

I tried this ::

```
public class UserInfo
{

    public string UserId { get; set; }   
    public string UserName { get; set; } // length should not exceed 20, if NULL pass "TBD"
    public string UserAddr { get; set; } // length should not exceed 120, if NULL pass "TBD"
    public string UserContact { get; set; } // length should not exceed 20, if NULL pass "TBD"

    string getAddress = CheckProperty(UserAddr,120);
 }
```

but getting the errors. How to call the **CheckProperty** function and pass the properties value to getRecord ?

Comment: Have you tried to use DataAnnotations to validate your properties? Read the article and tryi to implement this. I believe that is the best way to validate the properties of your classes. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256183/DataAnnotations-Validation-for-Beginner

Comment: Btw, the best way to send default data in your database is declare the default value of the field when you create your table. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Library/ms187872.aspx

Comment: @JúlioMurta    I need to check from the application side not from the database. Please suggest how can I do this.

Comment: @JúlioMurta  I need to use the function CheckProperty. Pleas suggest how can I do this

Comment: CheckProperty is an extesion method, so you just need to call UserAddr.CheckProperty(120).